# module not getting imported in django

Tags: django-models, python-import

I have downloaded pisa in python ,its been installed in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
folder
i have imported that in my project as *import ho.pisa as pisa*

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.conf import settings
import ho.pisa as pisa
import cStringIO as StringIO
import cgi
import os
from unipath import Path

PROJECT_ROOT=Path(__file__).ancestor(2)


def html_to_pdf(request):
    html  = render_to_string('custodialrecon/html_to_pdf.html', { 'pagesize' : 'A4', }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    result = StringIO.StringIO()
    pdf=pisa.pisaDocument(StringIO.StringIO(html.encode("UTF-8")),dest=result,link_callback=fetch_resources)
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), mimetype='application/pdf')
    return HttpResponse('Gremlins ate your pdf! %s' % cgi.escape(html))



def fetch_resources(uri, rel):
    path = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT.child('assets'), uri.replace(PROJECT_ROOT.child('static'), ""))
    return path
```

when ever i am running the projects,its showing `<i>ImportError: No module named ho.pisa</i>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
from ho import pisa
```

instead of

```
import ho.pisa as pisa
```